# How to extract source code from certain page?

Tags: html, vb.net, web

what i need is to extract the source code of a web page using vb.net, i have done it before, but there is a web page in which i cannot extract it correctly..

An example is http://jkanime.net/sket-dance/

what i do to extract it is

```
Dim SourceLink As String
SourceLink = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(TxtLink.Text)
TxtDescripcion.Text = SourceLink
```

But everytime i do that i only get this as source code:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=http://jkanime.net/sket-dance/'>
```

Not the whole page source code... Please Help Me.

Comment: What type is `TxtDescripcion`?

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger to see what the value of `SourceLink` is before it gets assigned to `TxtDescripcion.Text`?

Comment: `TxtDescripcion.text` is the description of the anime..
Is a richtextbox used to debug the value of sourcelink instead of looking in the textfile i created for the source code info of a page..

Comment: sourcelink value is the one mentioned before...
`<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='3; URL=http://jkanime.net/sket-dance/'>`

Comment: Have you looked into `WebClient.CachePolicy` property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cachepolicy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: how do you use it? for example in my code?

Comment: The server you are querying is using a `META` tag to refresh the page after 3 seconds, presumably to keep crawlers from grabbing the initial page load.  You'll have to work out with the content provider an alternative to scrape from their data sources.

Comment: @Claies ok, so i have this i investigated...
`Dim SourceLink As String

Dim webclient As System.Net.WebClient

webclient = New Net.WebClient()

CachePolicy=New RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache)

webclient.CachePolicy = CachePolicy


SourceLink = webclient.DownloadString(TxtLink.Text)`

Comment: but keep getting the meta tag..

Comment: There is nothing in your code that you can do to stop their server from refreshing after 3 seconds.  you are getting the initial page, which has **nothing** on it except the refresh meta.  They don't want you taking their data.

Comment: ohhhh so there is no possible way of doing this??